# Is there any way I can create a string variables with "commas" in batch programme

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a variable like this in Batch programme:

```
SET var=abc,def
```

This command runs fine in command line.
But when I put same line in a batch file it gives error:

> ```
> def not defined
> ```

Is there any other way I can create this string by concatenation or something?

I am basically checking for some directories present under current directory and saving names of present directory comma seperated
this is what my code looks like

SET "dirArray=null"
IF EXIST dir1 (
    IF %dirArray% EQU null (
        SET "dirArray=src/main"
    ) ELSE (
        SET "dirArray=%dirArray%,dir1"
    )
)
... // further more IF EXIST cases for different directories

Comment: There is nothing special about commas in a variable. Your error is somewhere else

Comment: You might want to edit your post with your batch file, or at-least the section(s) of importance. As jeb mentioned, a comma in a variable really isn't all that special.

Comment: Adding quotation marks around is a good practice to prevent poison characters ruin your code. E.g: `SET "var=abc,def"`

Comment: Please include more of your file, as `def` is not being set as a variable in this text. [Here's](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) the list of all characters that need escaping and how to do so, note a comma isnt one of these.

Answer (score 0):

@Arescet
Has indirectly answered the question
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php
the above link is list of characters that needs to be escaped
, should be escaped as ^,

so replacing set "dirArray=%dirArray%,dir1" with set "dirArray=%dirArray%^,dir1" works

thanks for the help guys

Comment: Seeing your code means that your `SET` works before, your problem was at another code line